# Jest: Add component children elements to snapshot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

When trying to run Sample.test.jsx with jest, below snapshot is created.

**Sample.jsx**

```
class Sample extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Link to={'/xyz'}>
        <div className={cx('l-tab')}>
             Click Me
        </div>
      </Link>
    );
  }
  }
```

**Sample.test.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

test('testing Component', () => {
  const component = mount(
    <Sample />
    );

  expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

**Snapshot**

```
exports[`testing Component 1`] = `
 <Link to="/xyz" />
`
```

**Question**- How can I get the child elements of **Link** in the snapshot?

**Snapshot expected:**

```
exports[`testing Component 1`] = `
 <Link to="/xyz" >
   <div className='l-tab'>
         Click Me
    </div>
  </Link>
`
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't *want* to do shallow rendering, you could just try the `react-test-renderer` instead of `enzyme`:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Sample from './Sample';

test('testing Component', () => {
  const component =  renderer.create(<Sample />).toJSON();
  expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

enzyme mount `children` method..

```
.children([selector]) => ReactWrapper
```

from enzyme mount docs :

```
const wrapper = mount(<ToDoList items={items} />);
expect(wrapper.find('ul').children()).to.have.length(items.length);
```

ref: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/children.html

you can also find the element by className :

```
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent />);
expect(wrapper.find('.my-button').hasClass('disabled')).to.equal(true);
```

ref: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/hasClass.html